# Writing foreign language characters to json using utf8

Tags: python, json, utf-8

Using Python 2(2.56)I am attempting to write Brazilian Portuguese(however could be any supported language) to a json file. When I write the characters to a log file is displays perfectly, however when written to the json file the characters are incorrect.

Here is my code

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    data = u'ÁàâãçêíóôõúÜ'
    utfdata=data.encode('utf-8')
    LOG.info("utfdata:"+utfdata)
    Name = utfdata

    s = s.replace("\"NAME\"", Name)
    f = open('appmodel.json',"w")
    f.write(s.encode('utf-8'))
```

Also tried replacing the open() method with 
f = codecs.open('appmodel.json', encoding='utf-8', mode='w+')

Output received in json file is ÃÃ Ã¢Ã£Ã§ÃªÃ­Ã³Ã´ÃµÃºÃ instead of Áàâãçêíóôõú

Could someone tell me if this is a python bug or if I am doing something wrong

Comment: How are you viewing the output file?  It looks like it's correct & valid UTF-8, but you're viewing it as Latin-1.

Comment: @jwodder: How do you know what it looks like?

Comment: @martineau: He posted the output (`ÃÃ Ã¢Ã£Ã§ÃªÃ­Ã³Ã´ÃµÃºÃ`).

Comment: @jwodder: Yes, and my understanding of the question is how to get it to be the `Áàâãçêíóôõú` it should be in the json file — because `ÃÃ Ã¢Ã£Ã§ÃªÃ­Ã³Ã´ÃµÃºÃ` is **not** correct.

Comment: @martineau: `ÃÃ Ã¢Ã£Ã§ÃªÃ­Ã³Ã´ÃµÃºÃ` is (almost, with modifications for control characters) what you get if you save `Áàâãçêíóôõú` as UTF-8 but view it as Latin-1.  The solution to the question is to view the file as UTF-8, and how to accomplish that depends on how the OP is viewing the file in the first place.

Comment: `try open('appmodel.json',"wb")` does ist change anything? Are you using Python 2?

Comment: Yes I am using Python 2. So What I received was ÃÃ Ã¢Ã£Ã§ÃªÃ­Ã³Ã´ÃµÃºÃ in both firefox and notepadd++. So did not change anything.